# if condition + check isnull() is true

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I have a df that looks like this:

```
     carry_dt    sedol    prime_broker_id  legal_entity   strategy  NewCarryRate  
716   2018-01-02  B1T84Z4    CITI             USSA-AGG      USSA       NaN
```

I would like to check if there are any NaN values in the column 'NewCarryRate' and replace them

I created an if condition:

```
 if (allHoldings['NewCarryRate'].iloc[[i]].isnull())==True:
        allHoldings['NewCarryRate'].values[i]= 100
```

I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know I can use `np.where` but I find it easier to use if condition here because I can add more rows under the if condition if I wanted to.

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: You use a double array at `.iloc[[i]]` don't you mean `.iloc[i]`? And you dont have to use the `== True` it's redundant

Comment: @Ron  Thank you for you answer  i did `.iloc[[i]]` to select the row i. is it not correct?  also when I do `allHoldings['NewCarryRate'].iloc[i].isnull())` i get an error

Comment: I'm not sure about what is correct, I've never used pandas. But what are you trying to accomplish with it? Do you want to check if the whole row is null?

Comment: And have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922103/5686835)

Comment: I am looking to check if the column['NewCarryRate'] of row i is NaN

Comment: @SBad actually, according to your description, you're just looking to replace such values by 100; explicitly check if row i is NaN is not your end in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for this:

```
allHoldings['NewCarryRate'].fillna(100, inplace=True)
```

---

The entire `if` clause is unnecessary - `fillna` does this. The reason you're getting this error is that

```
if (allHoldings['NewCarryRate'].iloc[[i]].isnull())==True:
```

it can be true for some entries and false for some; the interpreter can't know if to perform the clause or not.